# MVC - Pulling a database field from the model and using it in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model

I'm trying to implement a database field from the model and use it in the controller.

So for example.

In **Employees.cs** *Model* class, there is a field **AccIsActive** and I want to use it in the controller so I could do a conditional statement.

I want to do a conditional statement so only the list view can check if AccIsActive is true so I could show the data. I don't want to do this in the front end as it can be easily modified.

This is what I have so far in my **List** method.

```
public ActionResult List()
        {

            IList<Employee> employees;

            EmpContext emp = new EmpContext();
            employees = emp.Employees.ToList();

            return View(employees);
        }
```

I'm trying to do something like...

```
if (AccIsActive == true)
{

.....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the active results with linq

```
employees = emp.Employees.Where(e => e.AcclsActive).ToList();
return View(employees);
```